# Python _io.TextWrapper error when using open method

Tags: python, string, tkinter, operating-system

So I am trying to open a .txt file and I am having trouble getting the method to work correctly. I am sure this is some simple mistake but for the life of me I cannot figure out what the problem is. I appreciate any help.

This is the segment of code in question:

```
self.cleanpath = os.path.abspath(self.file)
self.read = open(self.cleanpath, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
print(self.file)
print(self.read)
```

And this is the output:

```
C:/Users/Willett/Documents/EBAY_GRIEVANCE_1.txt
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\Willett\\Documents\\EBAY_GRIEVANCE_1.txt' mode='r' encoding='utf-8'>
```

Obviously my intention is to output the content of the .txt file to the self.read variable.

Comment: You need to call the method: `self.read()`

Comment: `self.read` is the open file object, you need to call its `read()` function to get the file content: `self.read.read()`.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling the method, instead you are printing the method's `__repr__`, which results in `<_io.TextIOWrapper ...>`:

```
file = open(self.cleanpath, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
print(file.read())
```

Comment: That was exactly the issue. Cant believe I missed that. Thanks so much for the quick reply!

Comment: @JacobWillett if this has solved the issue, then mark it as the correct answer